# FBLPromises Framework not found

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am tryin to install Firebase using cocoapods so I may send push-notifications to user devices. However, everytime I follow the instructions step by step, I get this error that says "framework not found FBLPromises". Anyone have any ideas how to fix? Everything I have looked up online does not work.

Answer (score 52):

The following worked for me:

What probably happened (for anyone still looking) is that after running

```
    pod install
```

in your project's directory, you are still building the ".xcodeproj" file instead of running the newly created ".xcworkspace" from the pod install. Remember, after pod installing, you MUST do edits on and work with the .xcworkspace instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I open up the .xcworkspace file by double clicking on it and it still gives me the error. Unless I am not opening it up correctly?

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot. I encountered an error at my first attempt. But what I did was delete the project with errors and started with a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Pod target and add **arm64** in **Excluded Architecture**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and I solved it by going to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... and selecting Find Implicit Dependencies. After that, the project was able to build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably late but I managed to fix it by linking FBL promises in my podfile to the rest of the project!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will try this when I start working on the project again. Could you explain a little more in depth what you actually did? As i am not too familiar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the *project > Targets*. Select your target. Then click on *Build Settings*. Find "Runpath searches path" and add "$(PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/PromisesObjC". It worked for me, but it gave me another error dealing with another missing lib, so I had to do it again until all libs were found.

Comment: did not helped for me

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is still struggling with that:
add $(inherited) to your app FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS for building and release.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that has this issue when installing Firebase SDK with SPM, go to your build settings and remove the framework from `Other Linker Flags` if it is present.

[image: Linker flags]

The issue (re)appeared after I migrated the SDK from Cocoapods to SPM. It seems that every framework and their dependencies installed from cocoapods get listed in the linker flags while those of SPM doesn't. So you may also remove all traces of the Cocoapods FB librairies from the flags I think.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Pod target and set **Build Active Architecture Only = YES** For Debug Environments
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Simply setting Build Active Architecture: Debug - Yes, Release - No fixed this for me. I had it set to No, No before. I think this matches the setting in the Pods project.

Answer (score -4):

1. Open Podfile by typing the command `open Podfile` in the folder of the project using the terminal.
2. Type `pod Promises`

Done