# impossible to build flutter on device or simulator in my mac

Tags: xcode, flutter

after two week... I successed upload xcode and catalina OS , zsh ... all could be good but have always error and can't launch my app on my physical device or simulator. Always error after Xcode build.

Things interesting, I remove App_review package from pubspec.yaml but I have always error with it...
If I launch flutter example it works, but If I use certain package like admob who worked before, or app review I have this errors. I can remove app_review package but remove ad mob no...

Edit: I remove all packages who show error, but have always this error
Here is my physical device error :

```
Xcode's output:
↳
   
    ld: framework not found FBLPromises
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel

    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Here is the error when I use simulator :

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: framework not found FBLPromises
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'in_app_purchase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'in_app_purchase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7s to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Comment: I've had a similar issue and I couldn't get out from it. I moved to Flutter's beta channel, downloaded the SDK and then came back to master. After a flutter clear, it worked like a charm

Comment: It's hard to identify the exact issue from flutter log. Try running the app via Xcode and you will get a clear and precious error message.

Comment: Aawaz Gyawali  I have remove all packages, that remove somes issues but have this last => 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742292/how-to-fixe-xcode-build-error-fblpromises

Comment: Try this, create a new project using the same package in a different directory in FLutter and copy all the .dart files and .yaml to the new project and then try to open the new project in Xcode and  run it,

Comment: Yes currently it’s work when i create a new projet with my old flutter file ( without 3 package who make problemes ( app_review/ audioplayeur/ad_mob) but it’s not very important i can do without it) but i don’t understant where is the probleme with my projet

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62054777/13625305)

Answer (score 2):

Open Runner.xcodeproj with xCode in ios folder, choose File menu, then select "Project Settings...". In Build System, choose Legacy Build System and run again.

Answer (score 2):

I have select legacy build system
, now I have this last error

```
  === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    ld: framework not found FBLPromises
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: trye this, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43591

Comment: I try but I'm not exactly in this case, my Xcode is 11.5 and build phase change, so I have flutter.firwmware for example. I change also my flutter version with last version , but have some trouble with packages. After flutter package get, All my package become red, like not loaded ... so impossible to build xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this thread and ensure that you are not accidentally overriding the VALID_ARCHS build setting: [What does warning "Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768723/what-does-warning-mapping-architecture-arm64-to-x86-64-mean)

Comment: not working i have now  
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386 ...