# Framework not found FBLPromises (Swift Package Manager)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I've seen this problem listed elsewhere, but it always seems to be linked to a Cocoapods installation of Firebase. My problem is the opposite - trying to upgrade from pods to SPM has given me this problem when I try to compile:

```
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
```

I'm currently running Xcode 13.3 on a Mac Mini with an M1 chip, but the problem was present in earlier versions of Xcode.

Previously I had Disk (https://github.com/saoudrizwan/Disk) installed via SPM and Firebase/Messaging and Twilio (5.5.1) installed via Cocoapods. I ran `pod clean` and `pod deintegrate`, deleted all the Pod files etc and have installed Twilio and Firebase Messaging using SPM. This gives me the following Package Dependencies (and you can see that Promises 2.0.0 has been added successfully):

[image: PackageDependencies]

The top result I get when I look into this is [FBLPromises Framework not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510333/fblpromises-framework-not-found), and the second answer suggests adding arm64 as an excluded architecture, but doing that gives me further problems (warning and error below), and I'd rather not exclude an architecture blindly and then go down a rabbithole of trying to fix that when it might not be the solution to my original problem.

Warning and error when I try to exclude arm64 architecture:

`None of the architectures in ARCHS (arm64) are valid. Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or updating it to include at least one value from VALID_ARCHS (arm64, arm64e, armv7, armv7s) which is not in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (arm64).`

`error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/myName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-exchrqebmyccatebeoxupvxpdsul/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/project.app/project' (in target 'project' from project 'project')`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've not checked to make sure I've not introduced other errors further down the line, but I think the problem was caused by Linker Flags being retained in the build settings.

I went to the Target -> Build Settings -> Linking and deleted everything under 'Other Linker Flags' (OTHER_LDFLAGS is how this is reflected in the project.pbxproj file according to my git diff).

File now compiles and runs successfully, if I find some subtle bugs later that might be caused by this I shall edit this answer accordingly!

Comment: I had this issue when switching a package from Cocoapods to SPM and this definitely was the right fix. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you don't need to delete all linker flags, just the frameworks that are causing issues. But question is why does this work? Why there are frameworks added to linker flags? Is that something automatically added when installed with Cocoapods and is causing issues when migrating to SPM?

Comment: @stackich it looks like Cocoapods may not be removing the `-framework Pod` flag when removing a pod (by removing it's entry from your podfile). The weird thing, at least in my case, only one configuration was affected.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This was really difficult to find.

Comment: Amazing! You save my day!

Comment: Got the same problem after migrating all my PODs to SPM, with SDWebImage library. I've deleted all it was in the Other Linker Flags list and my project compiles now. Thanks.