# my pod framework are missing after updating xcode to 14.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

my project worked perfectly before i update xcode to 14.3.1
now it looks like xcode can't find my frameworks
i drop images of parts of my project below.

after build my project this is console error
[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHoOo.png)
and this is navigation error
[nav error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crubw.png)

this is my podfile [podfile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9rk7.png)

and xcode show my framework file names red color it looks like it can't find them [nav image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8aQ1.png)

i have tried these solutions but they didn't worked for me

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799712/20693520
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573086/20693520

Comment: you need to run 'pod install' again and open the .xcworkspace white file, not the blue one

Comment: @ArturMarchetto thank you, but i have done that before and didn't work.
i remove and reinstall pod, update repo and still didn't work :(

Comment: if it's a very old project maybe something got lost, you can try to create a new project and import the files over.
The missing OBJC symbols is usually an issue with how the libraries are linked in the project.
Google missing OBJC_XXX symbols and you'll find good solutions

Comment: @ArturMarchetto no it's not old at all, and i found the solution finally. Thank you for your time Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying different things this works for me

i've added this code to 2 places

1. Target > Build Setting > Linking > Other Linker Flags

   `$(inherited)`
2. Target > Build Setting > Linking > Runpath Search Path

   `$(inherited)`